# How to avoid ASP.Net creating a new WorkerAppDomain, or starting a (console) app in the WorkerAppDomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler, cassini

What can I do to avoid ASP.Net creating a new WorkerAppDomain for my Custom IHttpHandler.
As far I know the problem is the SimpleHttpworkerRequest which runs a new Appdomain.

I have an embedded cassini webserver, with this webserver I want to create a webinterface for my app. but I can't access the objects of my app, because the webrequests are created in a new Appdomain. If possible I want to avoid any kind of remoting.

Maybe I have a wrong perspective on the problem. What else is possible to create a web interface for an application?

Comment: I have some custom IHttpHandler, these handler must run in the same appdomain as the cassini-server-runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can configure the way cassini works this deeply, but you can find the sources here if you want to change it: [Cassini for Framework 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx)